# I'm having issues in Discord.js with functions like client.users.cache.size

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Whenever I try to use a function like `client.users.cache.size` or `client.guilds.size`, they keep giving me an error like *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'guilds' of undefined"* or *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"*.

I was also trying to use `let guilds = client.guilds.cache.array().join('\n')` but it also throws the same error.

Command's code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: 'Views the bot\'s stats',
    execute(client, message) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed
        .setDescription(`In ${client.guilds.size} servers`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

Bot's main file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require ('quick.db');

const client = new Discord.Client
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => path.join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);

getDirectories(__dirname + '/commands').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`${category}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`ready!.`);
    console.log(token);
    
    // Activities  
    const activities_list = [ 
        `Serving Tacos | .help`,
        `Preparing Orders | .help`
    ];
    
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]);
    }, 10000);
});

//Joined Guild
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {   
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FFFF33')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`746423099871985755`).send(EmbedJoin)
});

//Left Guild
client.on("guildDelete", (guild) => {
    const EmbedLeave = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FFFF33')
    .setTitle(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}.`)
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(`746423099871985755`).send(EmbedLeave)
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `${message.author}, wrong usage`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

process.on("error", () => {
    console.log("Oops something happened!");
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and add some code so we can see what doesn't work.

Comment: okay, i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `client.guilds` returns a manager, so you have to use `client.guilds.cache.size`. The rest of the code works fine.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: 'Views the bot\'s stats',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed
        .setDescription(`In ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
}
```

In your main bot file you're only passing the `message` and the `args` (in this order) to `command.execute()`. You can add the `client` too, and update the parameters in your command's code to match this order.

```js
try {
  command.execute(message, args, client);
} catch (error) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: it gives me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"

Comment: How do you call the `execute()` method? Is `client` the `new Discord.Client();` and `message` the incoming message?

Comment: yes just as you said `client` is the `new Discord.Client`and message is the `client.on('message', message => {` i can edit my post with the main file's full code if that would help

Comment: That would be probably helpful. Not sure if I can check it in the next few hours though, but I will try.

Comment: Okay i edited it, thanks for your time btw

Comment: I've just updated my answer, hopefully it works as expected.

Comment: i updated the main file's command.execute as you said and it keeps giving me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined` I'm so confused

Comment: So there isn't any way to fix this?

Comment: Updating the order should have fixed that. Can you share the updated code somehow?

Comment: ohh my bad i didn't do it in order sorry, it worked